# How to refresh a section of HTML page

Tags: php, html

I require a section in my HTML page which will update whenever user perform a successful data entry. The data entry comes from input from user into MySQL database, then I will query the table filter by status is Success and sort by creation date DESC.

I do not want to refresh the whole page, just the section/div (I don't know which practice to use). What are the best method to achieve this? Ajax? iframe?

Comment: Put in a `<div>` and use `javascript`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this.

```
<!DOCUMENT>
<html lang="en">
 <head>     
  <title>Auto Load and Refresh Div Every 10 seconds</title>     
  <style>
    #auto_load_div>div{width:100%;max-width:320px;}
  </style>     
 </head>
 <body>     
     <div id="auto_load_div"></div>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
     <script>
      function auto_load(){
        $.ajax({
          url: "data.php",
          cache: false,
          success: function(data){
             $("#auto_load_div").html(data);
          } 
        });
      }     
      $(document).ready(function(){     
        auto_load(); //Call auto_load() function when DOM is Ready     
      });     
      //Refresh auto_load() function after 10000 milliseconds
      setInterval(auto_load,10000);
   </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Also like this.

HTML

```
<div id="divID"> <!-- THE DATA FROM THE FORM VIA PHP --> </div>
<form id='foo' onsubmit="return false">
 <input type='text' name="yourname">
 <input type='submit'>
</form>
```

display the response in the html to which u gave an id.

JQUERY

```
$('#foo').submit(function(event){
  $.ajax({
    url: 'index.php',
    type: 'post',
    dataType:'html',   //expect return data as html from server
   data: $('#foo').serialize(),
   success: function(response, textStatus, jqXHR){
      $('#divID').html(response);   //select the id and put the response in the html
    },
   error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
      console.log('error(s):'+textStatus, errorThrown);
   }
 });
});
```

write ur html here... i am just printing the post variable here... u can use `<table>` (html) as required

index.php

```
echo $_POST['yourname'].
```

Comment: All the database select statement will be done in the data.php?

Comment: @4LeaveCover That is correct, based on the first solution.

Comment: in this case my data.php will be exposed to public. Should i be concerned?

Answer (score 0):

`Ajax` will be best suited for your application. However, from whatever you've stated, I think you'll be needing to deal with `web-sockets` as you'll have to continuously listen to the database changes. Try to find out how do you implement it in `php` if you haven't done it yet.

Comment: Instead of checking database frequently, are there any ways to push notification after insert into database? It's like the reverse way if you know what I mean.

Comment: obviously yes. after successful return message from database to your application, you can always ping the other server (using ajax here) to change specific page contents.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to this implementation, hope you don't mind. Do I ask my hosting provider if they allow web-socket? What is the feature that can push a notification in MySQL?

Comment: there are libraries for `web-socket` and about the notification thing, you can hard-code it or even find some libraries again. It totally depends upon your application and how do you want it to behave like.